# Why is sizeof empty class 1 byte and not 2 bytes in C++?

Tags: c++

```
class A         //class A
{
   class B     // class B nested inside the class A
    { };       // empty class
};
```

Why does the above class have a size of 1 byte instead of 2?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why do you think it should be 2 bytes large? (This might not be a duplicate; if the other question/answer doesn't help you, we can reopen this question. But only if it's a distinct question.)

Comment: @user2431889 Sizes of both A and B are one. You can add even more levels of nesting but empty class means empty class no matter what it has within it and where is it placed. Here, its just empty class nested within a class and the entire thing is still empty class. Remember class is just a template to declare objects, nesting an empty class within a class will not make it non-empty.